# React Native Release Crash

Tags: android, react-native

Iam getting the below error when I open the release build.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules Process: com.package.name, PID: 28695 com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: typeAnnotation, stack: @980:17088 v@2:1473 @979:425 v@2:1473 @978:339 v@2:1473 @971:6338 v@2:1473 @970:139 v@2:1473 @969:218 v@2:1473 @968:117 v@2:1473 @882:1330 v@2:1473 @545:542 v@2:1473 @406:344 v@2:1473 @6:57 v@2:1473 d@2:875 global code@1766:3 at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372) at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:151) at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Dev build is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try looking in your code for something like @babel/types; for me, it was to remove `import { breakStatement } from '@babel/types';` then everything was working fine

Answer (score 0):

Please check Your MainActivity.java class. If you are using Firebase then check google-Service.json file check package name. this is package name issue ... check all the package name in you app. I think package name is ok then all will be ok thanks..

Comment: package name is ok in all the places, still facing the issue.